# How to refer to sequentially named HTML Canvases and Picture Objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, syntax

what is the correct syntax for looping through sequentially named Canvases and sequentially named picture objects... like so:
How do I go from this:

```
canvas0Context.drawImage(pic0 ,shapePositionX[0], shapePositionY[0], pic0.width * shapeScaleX[0], pic0.height * shapeScaleY[0]);
canvas1Context.drawImage(pic1 ,shapePositionX[1], shapePositionY[1], pic1.width * shapeScaleX[1], pic1.height * shapeScaleY[1]);
canvas2Context.drawImage(pic2 ,shapePositionX[2], shapePositionY[2], pic2.width * shapeScaleX[2], pic2.height * shapeScaleY[2]);
```

To this.....how to refer to "canvas0Context", "canvas1Context", "canvas2Context"...and "pic0", "pic1", "pic2"?

```
for( counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++){
    canvas0Context.drawImage(pic0 ,shapePositionX[counter], shapePositionY[counter], pic0.width * shapeScaleX[counter], pic0.height * shapeScaleY[counter]);
}
```

Comment: Ideally `pic`, `canvasContext`, etc. should be arrays too.

Answer (score 0):

`pic0`, `pic1`, `pic2` html objects, and `canvas0Context` is the context of a canvas. That means they could (and possibly should) have an `id` or `name`. Using `document.getElementById()` you can iterate over them.

```
for(counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++){
    let pic = document.getElementById("pic"+counter);
    let canvasContext = document.getElementById("canvas"+conter).getContext("2d");
    canvasContext.drawImage(pic, shapePositionX[counter], shapePositionY[counter], pic.width * shapeScaleX[counter], pic.height * shapeScaleY[counter]);
}
```

Even more, you could name all of the canvas with the name `pic` and iterate over the collection of them:

```
let pics = document.getElementByName("pic")
let canvasContexts = [];
document.getElementById("canvas"+conter).forEach((e) => {canvasContext.push(e.getContext("2d");})

for (let i in document.getElementByName("pic")) {
    canvasContexts[i].drawImage(pics[i], shapePositionX[counter], shapePositionY[counter], pics[i].width * shapeScaleX[counter], pics[i].height * shapeScaleY[counter]);
}
```